# How to create a href tag with link_to and action 'create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a href tag like `href=contacts/create`. In my contacts_controller, I have a create GET action. I know this is against rails convention. I still need to create the above link using `options = {controller=> 'contacts', action=>'create'}`. It works for any other arbitrary action name

Answer (score 3):

First off this is really bad idea since [GET requests should be idempotent](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/). You're not just flouting convention - you're setting yourself and your users up for a *really bad time* since for example pressing the back and forward buttons will cause resources to be created - over and over. And there is guaranteed a better way to solve whatever you are trying to do such as:

```
# a "discrete form"
<%= button_to "Create contact", contacts_path, method: :post %>
# or use the rails ujs 
<%= link_to "Create contact", contacts_path, method: :post %>
```

If you ABSOLUTELY have do this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "contacts/create"
end
```

You can now do:

```
<%= link_to "Create", { controller: 'contacts', action: 'create' } %>
```

Congratulations, you broke the internets.

Comment: haha "Congratulations you broke the internets" I like that :D

Comment: unfortunately it is legacy code!! Someone has done some real good work  :(

Answer (score 3):

You can the hardcoded path option:

```
<%= link_to "Create", "contacts/create" %>
```

or the Rails generated path option:

```
<%= link_to "Create", { controller: "contacts", action: "create" } %>
```

This is not just against Rails' convention, but against sounds HTTP usage.  This often causes serious problems that you can't predict in advance.  Web crawling is just one of them, where something like the Google bot accidentally creates a new contact in your database, simply by crawling the page.  Or script kiddies who find you have a create link, and send 100,000 clicks to it in quick succession.

Numerous other issues happen like this, including, at one well-known time, Google Chrome pre-fetching GET urls from the page to "speed up the user experience"; this was felt far and wide by sites that had used this technique.  It's not an idle warning or a style issue: this can have a *disastrous* impact on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, this is against rails convention, but if absolutely necessary, you can do this from your controller:

```
options = {controller=> 'contacts', action=>'create'}
view_context.link_to url_for(options)
```

If you need the href to only be the path, you can do:

```
options = {controller=> 'contacts', action=>'create'}
view_context.link_to url_for(options.merge(only_path: true))
```